# Google App Engine dashboard showing unrealistic usage parameters

Tags: google-app-engine

See the image and usage of Search API.
[image: Screenshot of GAE dashboard showing unrealistic usage for Search API]

We have set a daily budget of $40. We have currently like 20-30 users for our app.

Other parameters like Datastore Read Operations, Frontend Instance Hours are also inflated.

Can anyone has any idea why GAE showing such high and unrealistic numbers?

**One more instance of similar issue:**
Within 2-3 minutes of the start of the daily cycle, we see that over 500 instance hours is used. Values for Datastore Read Operations, Datastore Write Operations and Outgoing Bandwidth are also inflated. This is well above our set daily limit of $5.
But the total "Estimated cost for the last x hours" is much less than the sum of the individual resource value (and seem to be in the right order of magnitude).
[image: resouce values within 2-3 minutes of the start of daily cycle]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400097/gae-instance-hours-100/31401482#31401482 ?

Comment: Earlier today, a number of users observed incorrect usage statistics being displayed by the App Engine dashboard in the Google Cloud Developer Console.  Some resources, especially Frontend Instance Hours, were shown with unrealistically elevated usage.

Comment: The dashboard has been returned to normal operation and our engineers are investigating to find and fix the root cause of the issue.  So far, the results of our investigation indicate that the issue was purely cosmetic, with no elevated billing or quota denials to any user application.  If your application encountered quota denials because of this issue, if you later observe elevated resource billing in your invoice for this month, or if you are still observing unrealistic usage in the App Engine dashboard, please notify Google Cloud Platform Support.